# Tightly crop styled Text in a Graphics box

Tags: graphics, options

I am running Mathematica 9, which I realize is quite old. I wrote the following code to output a `Graphics` environment containing some styled text. But, as you can see, the `Graphics` box containing the text is quite large.

What is the best/simplest way to crop the `Graphics` box -- either programatically or in the front end --so that it matches the approximate shape and size of the text?  If possible, I'm looking for a solution that works on Mathematica 9.

```
Graphics[
 Text[Style["(a) My Long Long Text", 28, FontFamily -> "Arial"]]
 ]
```

[image: graphics]

Answer (score 6):

Use `Show @* Rasterize` instead of `Graphics`:

```
Show @ Rasterize @ text
```

[image]

```
Head @ %
```

> ```
> Graphics
> ```

Alternatively, use the option `PlotRange` to specify the vertical range:

```
text = Text[Style["(a) My Long Long Text", 28, FontFamily -> "Arial"]]

Graphics[text, PlotRange -> {-.1, .1}]
```

[image]

`PlotRange -> {All, {-.1, .1}}` gives the same result.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using the `AspectRatio` option to tighten up the graphics viewport. It turns out that setting that option to any value lower than a certain threshold, which depends on the characteristics of the given text, will work. So it is easy to find one by trial-and-error.

```
Graphics[Text[Style["(a) My Long Long Text", 28]], AspectRatio -> .09]
```

[image: text]

However, should you not want to use trial-and-error, you can resort to `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
  Graphics[Text[Style["(a) My Long Long Text", 28]], AspectRatio -> r],
  {{r, .15}, .005, .15, .001, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: Manipulate]